# Is there a better way to show the active tab in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.1 tab content and nav tabs. I have next links in my tab content so users can click next instead of clicking the tab and after using those next buttons I want the correct tab to show depressed.

I noticed when I had the links the tab was not showing as depressed because the li active class wasn't being added. I put together this JavaScript to make it work, but I feel there should be an easier way?

DOM:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#cardType" data-toggle="tab">1) Select a package</a></li>
    <li><a href="#address" data-toggle="tab">2) Address package</a></li>
    <li><a href="#amount" data-toggle="tab">3) Specify Gift Amount</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pay" data-toggle="tab">4) Pay</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="cardType">
            <a href="#address" data-toggle="tab">Next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="address">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="amount">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="pay">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript to depress the tabs when the next link is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        e.target // activated tab
        e.relatedTarget // previous tab

        var targetTab = e.target.href.split('#')[1];
        console.log(targetTab);
        $(".nav-tabs a").parent().removeClass('active');
        $(".nav-tabs a[href=#" + targetTab + "]").parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

I've also tried using .show but that doesn't depress the correct tab for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                e.target // activated tab
                e.relatedTarget // previous tab

                var targetTab = e.target.href.split('#')[1];
                $('#myTab a[href="' + targetTab + '"]').tab('show');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').tab('show')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution, change your JS to:

```
$('a[data-nexttab]').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('nexttab');
    $('.nav-tabs li:eq(' + id + ') a').tab('show');   
});
```

And next button HTML to:

```
<!-- Note that the id is 0-indexed -->
<a href="#address" data-nexttab="1">Next</a>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWyBU/)

---

**UPDATE**

If you have multiple sets of tabs, this will break, so you can change the JS to this:

```
$('a[data-nexttab]').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('nexttab');
    $(this).closest('.tab-content')
           .siblings('.nav-tabs')
           .find('li:eq(' + id + ') a')
           .tab('show');   
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWyBU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you include the jquery and bootstrap.js file, there is no need for custom javascript

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rQfa7/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have those both included. the issue is cosmetic, where the correct tab is not depressed on clicking next. I'll update my question to be more clear.